# Microsoft graph differentiating between an email and a message on Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am making an app which involves displaying your emails onto an interface, and it uses the Microsoft graph api to get the data from the person's Microsoft account. The only problem is that included in the call for someones email: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages, is all of the messages that they have sent over Microsoft Teams. Is there a way that I can either call for ONLY emails, or could I sort between them within the bulk messages call. Upon inspection it seems as though there are no differences between emails and the messages on Microsoft Teams. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `/messages` endpoint returns your Inbox from Exchange Online. Not only does it only contain emails, it has no relation to Microsoft Teams at all.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur does this mean that there is no appropriate call I can make which would result in me getting back all emails of a microsoft exchange account?

Comment: Not as a single call. You need to fetch them by folder.

Comment: Actually, /me/messages returns messages from all folders, as Richard says below. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/messages` I believe, and confusingly, returns **items** from **any** folder in your mailbox.  Teams may store conversations in your user mailbox as a non-email item and thus they are showing up in the graph under `/messages`

You will need to specify the folder explicitly.  This will, in effect, limit to showing you email message items. EG. `/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages`

You may also want to file a bug about Teams' conversations showing up in `/messages` which differs from the documentation (which states it returns "mail").  They should be adding a type filter when the Graph queries Exchange.

Comment: Yep, this is correct. `/me/messages` returns messages from all mail folders in the mailbox. I don't think Teams actually saves messages in the mailbox (like Skype for Business does), but I could be wrong. If it does, and assuming the feature is like SfB, the convos are saved as mail items, which is why they come back in the query. They're stored in the Conversation History folder if you're curious :)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, It is all emails in /me/messages Except "recoverableitemsdeletions" folder.